# PySpark - Can i pivot a running window content on the current row with Window.rowsBetween()?

Tags: pyspark, pivot

iam trying to understand the window function of pyspark.
I want to build a pivoted table based on a running window.
The data might look like the following:

```
time | data
0023 |    g
0025 |    h
0026 |    x
0031 |    y
0034 |    z
```

and after pivoting it should look like

```
time | data | time | data | time | data
0023 |    g | null | null | null | null
0025 |    h | 0023 |    g | null | null
0026 |    x | 0025 |    h | 0023 |    g
0031 |    y | 0026 |    x | 0025 |    h 
0034 |    z | 0031 |    y | 0026 |    x
```

so it always takes the last 2 preceding rows and pivots them on the current row.

I tried to achieve this with something like:

```
window = Window.rowsBetween(-2, Window.currentRow)
windowed = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window)).pivot("rank")
```

but obviously iam doing something wrong as i end up with the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -2, currentrow$()) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$());'
```

Comment: what's your spark version?

Comment: I am using 2.4.3 actually

Comment: It can be done and I know how but you're going to end up with a huge dataframe if you do this. Can I ask what the bigger problem is that you're trying to solve with this? there must be a better way.

i.e. instead of a 200 x 2 df you'll have a 200x400 and as you're using pyspark I assume your data is quite big

Comment: Hi Dee, i belive you got me wrong. Concerning my example i start with a df of size 5x2 and would like to end up with a df of size 5x6, if i take your numbers and i start with 200x2 it should end up with 200x6

Comment: The bigger problem is, that i need to prepare a training dataset for a neural network, that takes as input a certain amount of history steps of timeseries data.

Answer (score 1):

For **`Spark2.4+`**, we can use **`array functions/higher order functions`** **`filter`**, **`array_repeat`** after **`collect_list`** of **`lags(time,data)`** over a **`window ordered by time.`**

```
df.show() #sample dataframe
#+----+----+
#|time|data|
#+----+----+
#|0023|   g|
#|0025|   h|
#|0026|   x|
#|0031|   y|
#|0034|   z|
#+----+----+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().orderBy("time")
df.withColumn("lag1", F.lag("time").over(w)).withColumn("lag2", F.lag("data").over(w))\
  .withColumn("collect", F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.array("lag1","lag2")).over(w),False)).drop("lag1","lag2")\
  .withColumn("collect", F.expr("""filter(collect,(x,i)-> i<=1)"""))\
  .withColumn("collect", F.when(F.size("collect")<2, F.flatten(F.array_repeat("collect",2)))\
                          .otherwise(F.col("collect")))\
  .select("time","data",*[(F.col("collect")[x][y]).alias("{}".format(z))\
                          for x,y,z in zip([0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],['time1','data1','time2','data2'])])\
  .show(truncate=False)


#+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
#|time|data|time1|data1|time2|data2|
#+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
#|0023|g   |null |null |null |null |
#|0025|h   |0023 |g    |null |null |
#|0026|x   |0025 |h    |0023 |g    |
#|0031|y   |0026 |x    |0025 |h    |
#|0034|z   |0031 |y    |0026 |x    |
#+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

For **`spark2.4.3`** use this, as this version does not support having **`index(i) argument in higher order function filter`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().orderBy("time")
df.withColumn("lag1", F.lag("time").over(w)).withColumn("lag2", F.lag("data").over(w))\
  .withColumn("collect", F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.array("lag1","lag2")).over(w),False)).drop("lag1","lag2")\
  .withColumn("collect", F.when(F.size("collect")>1,F.array(F.element_at("collect",1),F.element_at("collect",2)))\
                          .otherwise(F.col("collect")))\
  .withColumn("collect", F.when(F.size("collect")<2, F.flatten(F.array_repeat("collect",2)))\
                          .otherwise(F.col("collect")))\
  .select("time","data",*[(F.col("collect")[x][y]).alias("{}".format(z))\
                          for x,y,z in zip([0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1],['time1','data1','time2','data2'])])\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad and thanks for your response. When i try your solution, i end up with the following error message: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "The number of lambda function arguments '2' does not match the number of arguments expected by the higher order function '1'.;"

Comment: I checked on 2.4.3, the error is being raised because i used two args in filter function (x,i), where i is the index counter. it works perfectly if im on 2.4.5. check my updated solution for version 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mohammad and thanks a lot for the examples. I tested them and they worked.
During my still ongoing attempt to understand your 'not that expressive' ;) suggestions, i found out by myself, that my problem can also be solved with the code below. What do you think? I attached both physical plans. Why is your solution much more comlicated? Is there any performance reason or something, that i don't see?

This is the plan of your query (i don't really understand this, mine looks shorter, but i don't know, if it's faster):

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [time#542L, data#543, collect#578[0][0] AS time1#582, collect#578[0][1] AS data1#583, collect#578[1][0] AS time2#584, collect#578[1][1] AS data2#585]
+- *(3) Project [time#542L, data#543, CASE WHEN (size(collect#572) < 2) THEN flatten(array_repeat(collect#572, 2)) ELSE collect#572 END AS collect#578]
   +- *(3) Project [time#542L, data#543, filter(collect#563, lambdafunction((lambda i#574 <= 1), lambda x#573, lambda i#574, false)) AS collect#572]
      +- Window [time#542L, data#543, lag1#553L, lag2#557, sort_array(collect_list(_w0#592, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())), false) AS collect#563], [time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST]
         +- *(2) Project [time#542L, data#543, lag1#553L, lag2#557, array(cast(lag1#553L as string), lag2#557) AS _w0#592]
            +- Window [time#542L, data#543, lag(time#542L, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS lag1#553L, lag(data#543, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS lag2#557], [time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- Sort [time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                  +- Exchange SinglePartition, [id=#1223]
                     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[time#542L,data#543]
```

this is my own solution for now:

```
w = Window.orderBy(F.col("time"))
dfTest = df.withColumn("time1", F.lag(F.col("time"), 1).over(w))\
           .withColumn("data1", F.lag(F.col("data"), 1).over(w))\
           .withColumn("time2", F.lag(F.col("time"), 2).over(w))\
           .withColumn("data2", F.lag(F.col("data"), 2).over(w))
dfTest.show()

+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|time|data|time1|data1|time2|data2|
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  23|   g| null| null| null| null|
|  25|   h|   23|    g| null| null|
|  26|   x|   25|    h|   23|    g|
|  31|   y|   26|    x|   25|    h|
|  34|   z|   31|    y|   26|    x|
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

and the plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Window [time#542L, data#543, lag(time#542L, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS time1#707L, lag(data#543, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS data1#711, lag(time#542L, 2, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -2, -2)) AS time2#716L, lag(data#543, 2, null) windowspecdefinition(time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -2, -2)) AS data2#722], [time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- Sort [time#542L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Exchange SinglePartition, [id=#1557]
    +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[time#542L,data#543]
```

And this can also be done dynamically:

```
historyCount = 3
w = Window.orderBy(F.col("time"))
dfWithHistory = df
for i in range(1, historyCount + 1):
    dfWithHistory = dfWithHistory.withColumn("time{}".format(i), F.lag(F.col("time"), i).over(w))\
                                 .withColumn("data{}".format(i), F.lag(F.col("data"), i).over(w))
dfWithHistory.show()

+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|time|data|time1|data1|time2|data2|time3|data3|
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  23|   g| null| null| null| null| null| null|
|  25|   h|   23|    g| null| null| null| null|
|  26|   x|   25|    h|   23|    g| null| null|
|  31|   y|   26|    x|   25|    h|   23|    g|
|  34|   z|   31|    y|   26|    x|   25|    h|
+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Concerning my username and possible upcoming confusion: I accidentially created two accounts, user13213338 and stepper_m are both me :)

Comment: you can skip the Window frame `rowsBetween(..)` and use the same `Window.orderBy('time')` for all calculations. the default is set to `between unboundedPreceding and 0`, and Spark will optimize this internally.

Comment: @user13213338, you can also try a list comprehension other than using withColumn..

Comment: @jxc, what do you mean with that? Can you give an example?